# Why appears the wrong number

Tags: c

the code doesn't work and i don't know why but i'm a begginer in this language so the fault could be mine

```
#include <stdio.h>

int horascomeco(){
    int horasco; int minutosco; int totalcomeco;
    printf("-----A que horas e minutos começou o recolher?\nHoras:");
    scanf("%d", &horasco);
    printf("Minutos:");
    scanf("%d", &minutosco);
    printf("R:O recolher começou ás %d horas e %d minuto\n\n\n", horasco, minutosco);
    totalcomeco = horasco*60 + minutosco;
    printf("%d\n", totalcomeco);
    return  totalcomeco;
}

int horasapanhado(){
    int horasapa; int minutosapa;int totalapanhado;
    printf("-----A que horas e minutos foi apanhado?\nHoras:");
    scanf("%d", &horasapa);
    printf("Minutos:");
    scanf("%d", &minutosapa);
    printf("R:Voce foi apanhado ás %d horas e %d minutos\n\n\n", horasapa, minutosapa);
    totalapanhado = horasapa*60 + minutosapa;
    printf("%d\n", totalapanhado);
    return totalapanhado;
}

int tempodemulta(){     
    int minutosforadalei; 
    int horascomeco;               
    printf("%d\n", horascomeco);    
    int horasapanhado;             
    printf("%d\n", horasapanhado); 
    
    minutosforadalei = horasapanhado - horascomeco;
    
    printf("A sua multa vai ser respetiva a %d minutos fora do recolher obrigatorio", minutosforadalei);
}
 int main(){
     horascomeco();
     horasapanhado();
     tempodemulta();
     return 0;
 }
```

why appears 14705... ? minutosforadalei should be = 1 in that print
[image: code not working well]

---

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or easily copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: You print unitialized variables.

Answer (score 0):

```
int tempodemulta(){     
    int minutosforadalei; 
    int horascomeco;               
    printf("%d\n", horascomeco);    // no value assigned to horascomeco!
    int horasapanhado;             
    printf("%d\n", horasapanhado); // no value assigned to horaspanhado!

    minutosforadalei = horasapanhado - horascomeco;

    printf("A sua multa vai ser respetiva a %d minutos fora do recolherobrigatorio", minutosforadalei);
}
```

You are printing and calculating with variables that you have not assigned any value to yet. You have to assign a value to a variable before you try to use that value.